# I got a coinbase transaction and I don't know where it comes from

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction

I received a small payment from a coinbase transaction, but I haven't been mining nor I have signed up on a mining pool. Does this happen when someone accidentally sets my address instead of theirs when they mine? I think the probability for that to happen is pretty low.

Comment: Bitcoin mainnet? Can you provide info about the tx like txid?

Comment: Do you have a tx hash?

Comment: I sorted it out and posted an answer. Didn't want to post the tx hash due to privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, it was a withdrawal from [earn.com](https://earn.com) I made a few months ago which I forgot about. Wondering if they mine on their own.

Comment: Possibly, but whoever was mining also owned the coins Earn.com used to spend to you, unless the miner didn't want all of the reward (not likely).